# javascript array/object.push not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

input:

```
var variants = [];
$("div.product[data-variant]").each(function() {
    variants = [{name:chocolate, url:http://urltochocolate.de;
});
```

output:

```
$.each(optionList, function (i, el) {
  combo.append('<option value="'+ el.url +'">' + el.name + "</option>");
});
```

the above version works, but if i want to save all variants not only the last by adding a variants.push it won't work. i know push is an array function but how does it work for JS objects? or does a push work but then i use the wrong output function?

any help appreciated, it can't be so difficult, just not seeing the solution :(

EDIT:

it was not the missing Quotes, as chocolate and the url are only placeholders for jQuery Selectors

Comment: Please try variants.push({name:x, url:y});

Comment: adding a push like described above gives no results variants.lenght is also 0;

Comment: This means your data selector is wrong try $('div.product:data(variant)')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var variants = [];
$("div.product[data-variant]").each(function() {
    var name='name';
    var url='url';
    variants.push({name:name, url: url});
});
```

Comment: here i am just providing new values in name and url in the loop and you were giving the same value in your code. this is the difference. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
You are missing quotes in your json string.
Try like this.
var variants = [];
$("div.product[data-variant]").each(function() {
    variants.push([{name:'chocolate', url:'http://urltochocolate.de'}])
});
```